# load model with pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm newer in Pytorch,
I would like to "translate" those two lines in Pytorch code:

```
baseModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(target_model_path, compile=False)
    
baseModel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=[baseModel.get_layer('conv5_block3_out').output])
```

as experienced you can see it is trivial, but the answer matters too much to me

Answer (score 3):

To load model weights, you need to create an instance of the same model first, and then load the parameters using load_state_dict() method.

```
model = models.vgg16() # we do not specify weights, i.e. create untrained model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_weights.pth'))
model.eval()
```

We can then load the model like this:

```
model = torch.load('model.pth')
```